# Windows 11 Insider Dev Build no longer shuts down

Tags: shutdown, ubuntu-20.04, windows-insider, windows-11-preview

I am running **Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 22471 as Primary OS and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as Secondary OS.**

Before I was running Windows 11 Beta Build. I **switched to Dev Channel** and installed build 22471, from that time my Windows 11 PC is not **shutting down.** It just stays on the "Shutting Down" Screen.

I tried common solutions like disabling Fast Startup, etc. I also run an SFC scan which detected no integrity violations and a DISM Cleanup-Image also. Nothing is able to solve that problem.

My PC is compatible with Windows 11.

Microsoft Support suggested to Reset the PC / Ask in Tech Community (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/windows-11-insider-no-longer-shut-down/m-p/2836617)

**Resetting the PC** may fix the issue, but the problem may come again while installing updates. Even if I reset, I want Ubuntu as 2nd OS. I want to know whether this problem has any relation with **Ubuntu**?
**Please** give solutions to solve this problem

Comment: It has nothing to do with your Ubuntu partition. The problem is you're using a dev channel build, AKA the least stable build available. If you're wanting to participate in dev channel builds, expect problems and be willing to participate if the problems are known issues, providing feedback, check for updates, etc.

Comment: @DrZoo I know that. But in my family there is one more PC, which is incompaitable with Windows 11, and running the same Windows 11 Dev Build without Ubuntu. That PC is Shutting Down Properly.

Comment: @DevanarayananSM - All machines are different, what exactly happens, when you shutdown?

Comment: Open an admin command prompt and type shutdown /s  . Does that work?

Comment: @John That command also doesn't work

Comment: @Ramhound It just stays on "Shutting Down"

Comment: Do you have hybrid shutdown enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I reset my PC.
I tried everything but nothing was working. So I Clean Flashed Recovery Media from Manufacture, and then updated manually to Windows 11.

Thanks to Everyone...